# How to use our own crypto currency for transactions in smart contract

Tags: solidity, transactions, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I have created my own crypto-currency and tried sending it to an address through my ethereum wallet but can anyone tell me that how can I use this crypto-currency in another smart contract for transactions instead of ether?

Answer (score 1):

If you created an ERC20 standard contract, then you would have to reference the token contract in the new contract. Specifically the `transferFrom` method.

This is just a sample of what it could look like:

```
// Please don't use this code as it might contain security issues...
// It's just an example!

// Contract interface
contract TheTokenContract {
    // Copy Method Headers
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success);
}

contract YourNewContract {

    // Send TheToken
    function sendTheToken(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public {

        // Set token contract address
        address tokenContractAddress = <TokenAddress>;

        // Connect to TheTokenContract
        TheTokenContract token = TheTokenContract(tokenContractAddress);

        // Use TheTokenContract methods from Contract interface
        bool sendSuccess = token.transferFrom(_from, _to, _value);

    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried what you have said but getting an error which says "It seems this transaction will fail.If you submit it,it may consume all the gas you provide" while executing that contract. Can you help me to resolve it?